# Python stemmer issue: wrong stem

Tags: python, words, porter-stemmer

Hi i'm trying to stem words with a python stemmer, i tried Porter and Lancaster, but they have the same problem. They can't stem correclty words that end with "er" or "e".

for example, they stem

```
computer -->  comput

rotate   -->  rotat
```

this is a part of the code

```
line=line.lower()
line=re.sub(r'[^a-z0-9 ]',' ',line)
line=line.split()
line=[x for x in line if x not in stops]
line=[ porter.stem(word, 0, len(word)-1) for word in line]
# or 'line=[ st.stem(word) for word in line]'
return line
```

any idea to fix this problem?

Comment: What stemmer? Can you please include a minimal, complete, and verifiable example (with the source code).

Comment: Hi, i've updated the question, this issue occurs with both stemmers in the line where the stemmer is called

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i'm trying to obtain the stem of each word, for example cats -> cat or playing -> play

Comment: why is `computer -> comput` not correct ? I might be wrong but `comput` looks like a stem for `computing`, `computed`, `computer`, `computation`. Like `rotat` seems common to `rotate`, `rotation` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote [the page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_stem), `In computational linguistics, a stem is the part of the word that never changes even when morphologically inflected, whilst a lemma is the base form of the word. For example, given the word "produced", its lemma (linguistics) is "produce", however the stem is "produc": this is because there are words such as production.`
So your code is likely giving you correct results. You seem to expect a lemma which is not what a stemmer produces (except when the lemma happens to equal the stem)