# how to fix stopwords preprocessing inconsistency?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

I get a UserWarning thrown every time I execute this function. Here user_input is a list of words, and article_sentences a list of lists of words.

I've tried to remove all stop words out of the list beforehand but this didn't change anything.

```py
def generate_response(user_input):
    sidekick_response = ''
    article_sentences.append(user_input)

    word_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=get_processed_text, stop_words='english')
    all_word_vectors = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(article_sentences) # this is the problematic line
    similar_vector_values = cosine_similarity(all_word_vectors[-1], all_word_vectors)
    similar_sentence_number = similar_vector_values.argsort()[0][-2]
```

this is a part of a function for a simple chatbot I found here: https://stackabuse.com/python-for-nlp-creating-a-rule-based-chatbot/
it should return a sorted list of sentences sorted by how much they match the user_input, which it does but it also throws this `UserWarning: Your stop_words may be inconsistent with your preprocessing. Tokenizing the stop words generated tokens ['ha', 'le', 'u', 'wa'] not in stop_words`.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57340142/user-warning-your-stop-words-may-be-inconsistent-with-your-preprocessing where the question is more easily answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This user warning issue has been discussed [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/12897#issuecomment-519418161). As [@jnothman](https://github.com/jnothman) says:

> ...make sure that you preprocess your stop list to make sure that it is normalised like your tokens will be, and pass the list of normalised words as stop_words to the vectoriser.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with *preprocessing*.

From my personal experience, the stemming step in preprocessing leads to certain stems such as separating **ing** from the word **financing** to keep the stem **financ**. Eventually, these carry forward and cause inconsistencies with the TFIDF_Vectorizer -> stop_words list.

You can see this post to get some more info on this - [Python stemmer issue: wrong stem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193212/python-stemmer-issue-wrong-stem)

You can also try to avoid the stemming process and only tokenize. This will at least solve the inconsistencies error.